# No incoming Sms by SMPP from GoIP1 to Kannel or Ozeki

Tags: sms, gateway, smpp, kannel, ozeki

I set up GoIP1 (1 channel) with the latest GHSFVT-1.1-68-9 firmware to send/receive at least single part sms by SMPP with Kannel or Ozeki.
Outgoing messages sends out fine.
But incoming messages do not come to either Kannel or Ozeki but I can see it at GoIP1 Web UI.
For exxample there is no any deliver_sm in Kannel log.

Or may be some additional settings are necessary.
I enabled SMPP SMSC then specified ID, password, port, disabled "Channel number" and enabled "ENROUTE status".

By the way, Dinstar DWG2000F which I tested did it successfully.

Does GoIP1 not support route or give away received messages to sms gateways by SMPP ?
Or where am I wrong ?